# Ignore/catch "the type or namespace could not be found"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a bit of code that needs to react differently to each type inherited from a base class. (note: the base class and most of it's children are out of my control so I can't change parts of them)

```
public void MethodName(BaseClass myObject)
{
   switch (myObject.GetType().ToString().Substring(myObject.GetType().ToString()
               .LastIndexOf(".") + 1))
   {
        case "ChildA":
            GUILayout.Label(((ChildA)myObject).sprite.texture);
            break;
        case "ChildB":
            GUILayout.Label(((ChildB)myObject).animated[0].texture);
        case "ChildC":
            GUILayout.Label(((ChildC)myObject).default.texture);
            break;
    }
}
```

I have no way to predict what classes users will have in their assembly (ie A & B, none, all three, etc) but if they're missing any of them, this will obviously return an error since that object type doesn't exist.

Because each case is only called if that case's class exists, it will never actually be a problem. I just want Visual Studio & the compiler to shut up about

> The type or namespace name `ChildB' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

It seems like all the similar questions are asked (and answered) on how to fix it when their class isn't found - but I do not care about that at all because I KNOW it doesn't exist.    I have no intention of importing the class or running that line of code if the class isn't there

`try{ } catch(){ }` doesn't work

Comment: Try catch is for exceptions during runtime. You are getting a compilation error. You just need to add the `using` you need for ChildB.

Comment: If you don't have the types available at compile time you will have to use reflection for the detection part, and either reflection or `dynamic` for the usage part.

Comment: You're trying to mix compile time and runtime concepts. I'd suggest you need a firmer understanding on compilation because, if you had a good understanding, you wouldn't be capable of asking such a question.

Comment: I actually do understand the difference between runtime exceptions and compilation errors, thanks. never said I didn't know why try/catch doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can express that better without using Reflection.

If you are using C# 7 you can use [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching):

```
public void MethodName(BaseClass myObject)
{
    switch (myObject)
    {
        case ChildA a:
            GUILayout.Label(a.sprite.texture);
        case ChildB b:
            GUILayout.Label(b.animated[0].texture);
        case ChildC c:
            GUILayout.Label(c.default.texture);
    }
}
```

If not you could do something like this:

```
public void MethodName(BaseClass myObject)
{
    if (myObject is ChildA)
    {
        GUILayout.Label(((ChildA)myObject).sprite.texture);
    } else if (myObject is ChildB)
    {
        GUILayout.Label(((ChildB)myObject).animated[0].texture);
    } else if (myObject is ChildC)
    {
        GUILayout.Label(((ChildC)myObject).default.texture);
    } 
}
```

But your main issue is that you need to add a `using` so you can use ChildB.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a compiler error, not a runtime error. Therefore a `try-catch` will not help. The problem araises from the fact that the `ChildB`classe is in a different namespace. Add a

```
using The.Other.Namespace;
```

… at the top of your code, or, alternatively write

```
(The.Other.Namespace.ChildB)myObject
```

(This is useful if there is a name clash.)

Note: a compiler error results from a static analysis of your code. C# can detect syntax errors and obvious logical errors like using incompatible types, using unknown identifiers, un-assigned variables etc.. While at runtime you can get exceptions depending on actual values like: null-reference-exception, index-out-of-bounds-exception, division-by-zero-exception and a lot more.

---

You can get the class name with `myObject.GetType().Name`. Also, instead of withing `"ChildA"` it would be safer to write `nameof(ChildA)`, because then the C# compiler checks the name to be an existing name and the rename-refactoring will take this expression into account.

---

Even better: since C# 7.0 you can use pattern matching in the switch-statement:

```
switch (myObject)
{
    case ChildA childA:
        GUILayout.Label(childA.sprite.texture);
        break;
    case ChildB childB:
        GUILayout.Label(childB.animated[0].texture);
    case ChildC childC:
        GUILayout.Label(childC.default.texture);
        break;
}
```

---

Much better: implement an abstract getter only property `LabelTexture` in the base class and override it in the derived classes and let it return the appropriate texture. Then you could simply get the texture with `myObject.LabelTexture` (I don't know what type you are using for `texture`, so `Image` is just a guess):

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public abstract Image LabelTexture { get; }

    // ... other stuff
}

public class ClassA : BaseClass
{
    public override Image LabelTexture => sprite.texture;
}

public class ClassB : BaseClass
{
    public override Image LabelTexture => animated[0].texture;
}

public class ClassC : BaseClass
{
    public override Image LabelTexture => default.texture;
}
```

`public override Image LabelTexture => sprite.texture;` is just a shorter syntax for `public override Image LabelTexture { get { return sprite.texture; } }`

Then getting the right texture becomes as simple as:

```
public void MethodName(BaseClass myObject)
{
    GUILayout.Label(myObject.LabelTexture);
}
```

This is called [Polymorphism (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/polymorphism)